Merge two dataframes with only one column
I would like to merge two dataframes which have only one column say df1 and df2 as below. Expected output dataframe as df3.
import pandas as pd

data1 = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['name'])
data2 = [
    'B',
    'C',
    'D']

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['name'])

data3 = [
    ['A',],
    ['B','B'],
    ['C','C'],
    [None,'D']]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3,columns=['name_x','name_y'])

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)

Output:
  name
0    A
1    B
2    C
  name
0    B
1    C
2    D
  name_x name_y
0      A   None
1      B      B
2      C      C
3   None      D

Should I use merge to do it or any other way?

This question is similar to: Python join creates new column, putting NaN in index while right join on a common column. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Suggested duplicate is for how=right, you need how=outer here. E.g., one of the options: (df1.add_suffix('_x').merge(df2.add_suffix('_y'), how='outer', left_on='name_x', right_on='name_y')). There are a couple of variants in the answers there.

python3 report error: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns for key 'name'. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

You can hardly get that error on the code snippet I posted above: it does not feature a key name.

You would get that from doing what the OP in the suggested duplicate was doing, e.g., df1.join(df2,lsuffix='_x',rsuffix='_y',on='name',how='outer'), which as I explain in my answer on said post, is a wrong way of doing this, because it maps the values from name on the left (df1) to the index on the right (df2). Hence object (i.e., df1['name']) with int64 (i.e., df2.index).

got it, it works fine now, thanks

Quick hack, you could merge passing one of the keys as Series:
df1.merge(df2, left_on='name', right_on=df2['name'], how='outer').drop(columns='name')

Output:
  name_x name_y
0      A    NaN
1      B      B
2      C      C
3    NaN      D

If you don't drop you'll also get a column with the merged values:
df1.merge(df2, left_on='name', right_on=df2['name'], how='outer')

  name name_x name_y
0    A      A    NaN
1    B      B      B
2    C      C      C
3    D    NaN      D

If you had extra columns in the input, this would give you:
df1.merge(df2, left_on='name', right_on=df2['name'], how='outer')

  name name_x col1 name_y col2
0    A      A    x    NaN  NaN
1    B      B    x      B    x
2    C      C    x      C    x
3    D    NaN  NaN      D    x

generic method
If you have more than two inputs to combine, you can generalize with concat:
dfs = [df1, df2, df1, df2]
out = pd.concat(
    [
        d.set_axis(d['name']).add_suffix(f'_{i}')
        for i, d in enumerate(dfs, start=1)
    ],
    axis=1,
).reset_index(drop=True)

Output:
  name_1 name_2 name_3 name_4
0      A    NaN      A    NaN
1      B      B      B      B
2      C      C      C      C
3    NaN      D    NaN      D


df1.index = df1.name
df2.index = df2.name
df1.join(df2, how='outer', lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y')

You can add .reset_index(drop=True) if you don't want to have names in the index
Also, be careful with duplicates in df1 and df2, i.e. if you have n B's if df1 and m B's in df2, you will have n * m B's in df3.
